# Get filename and variable name from url in php which exist in the url

Tags: php

I want to get filename with  $_GET variable values from a url in php?

My url is http://dev.proprofs.com/helpdesk/admin/admin.php?t=email

I only want to retrieve the admin.php?t=email from the url?

How to do this? Please help.

Comment: `print_r($_GET)` and see what you get. Or be more specific and tell us what you're really trying to accomplish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this if you want get file name only.

```
print_r(pathinfo("/Your url go here",PATHINFO_BASENAME));
```

The out will get file name with extension.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, use **[pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)**

```
<?php
$filepath  = 'http://dev.proprofs.com/helpdesk/admin/admin.php?t=email';
$path_parts = pathinfo($filepath);

echo "dirname   : ".$path_parts['dirname']."\n";
echo "basename  : ".$path_parts['basename']."\n";
echo "extension : ".$path_parts['extension']."\n";
echo "filename  : ".$path_parts['filename']."\n";

?>
```

**OUTPUT** :

```
dirname   : http://dev.proprofs.com/helpdesk/admin
basename  : admin.php?t=email
extension : php?t=email
filename  : admin
```

**[DEMO](https://eval.in/664072)**